# Why not RESTful JSF?

Tags: jsf, rest

Struts2 is having built-in support for REST and so Spring MVC.

Ruby on Rails on the other hand is having a strong built in support for REST.

But JSF 2.2 specification does not contain any such support, and it seems that this is not an agenda in future JSF specifications as well!.

Why JSF team is simply ignoring REST?

Comment: Because JSF is a component based MVC framework, not a RESTful MVC framework. You're basically looking for the wrong tool for the job. You can't use a screwdriver to hit a nail. Instead of JSF, you should be looking at JAX-RS. Start here: http://jersey.java.net/use/getting-started.html (Jersey is for JAX-RS like as Mojarra is for JSF). However, if all what you ultimately want is "RESTful-like URLs" in JSF, look at PrettyFaces.

Comment: Not directly "RESTful", but nevertheless associated with request/action based frameworks, is the upcoming support for `view actions` in JSF 2.2. Another aspect that's often associated with REST and action based frameworks is stateless support, which is definitely on the radar and is currently the highest voted issue: http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-1055 (if you care for this topic, please vote and provide a comment)